# Not able to run select query after setting TTL in cassandra

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I have records already in cassandra DB,Using Java Class I am retrieving each row , updating with TTL and storing them back to Cassandra DB. after that if I run `select` query its executing and showing records. but when the TTL time was complete, If I run `select` query it has to show zero records but its not running `select` query showing `Cassandra Failure during read query at consistency ONE` error. For other tables `select` query working properly but for that table(to which rows I applied TTL) not working.

Comment: Please post your table schema and your queries.

Comment: I am using Java to fetch records & modify.. I have edited the post with table and java code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using common anti-patterns.

1) You are using **batches** to load data into two single tables, separately. I don't know if you already own a cluster or you're on your local machine, but this is not the way you load data to a C* cluster, and you are going to stress *a lot* your C* cluster. You should use batches only when you need to keep two or more tables in sync, and not to load a bunch of records at time. I suggest you the following readings on the topic:

- [DataStax documentation on BATCH](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html)
- [Ryan Svihla Blog](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e#.9z1lkzqe6)

2) You are using **synchronous** writes to insert your pretty indipendent records into your cluster. You should use **asynchronous** writes to speed up your data processing.

- [DataStax Java Drive Async Queries](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries)

3) You are using the **TTL** features in your tables, which per se are not that bad. However, an *expired* TTL **is** a tombstone, and that means when you `SELECT` your query C* will have to read all those tombstones.

4) You bind your prepared statement multiple time:

```
BoundStatement bound = phonePrepared.bind(macAddress, ...
```

and that should be

```
BoundStatement bound = new BoundStatement(phonePrepared).bind(macAddress, ...
```

in order to use *different* bound statements. This is not an anti-pattern, this is a problem with your code.

Now, if you run your program multiple times, your tables have a lot of tombstones due to the TTL features, and that means C* is trying hard to read all these in order to find what you wrote "the last time" you successfully run, and it takes so long that the queries times-out.

**Just for fun**, you can try to increase your timeouts, say 2 minutes, in the `SELECT` and take a coffee, and in the meantime C* will get your records back.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but fast TTLs are your enemies. If you just wanted to *refresh* your records then try to keep TTLs time high enough so that it doesn't hurt your performances. Or, a probably better solution is to add a new column *EXPIRED*, "manually" written only when you need to delete a record instead. That depends on your requirements.